# How to Remove Duplicate OUTPUT in SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem with a `ComboBox`, its items are being duplicated. How can I prevent this situation? Here is some images:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code sample used to populate it:

```
string SelectQuery = "SELECT   Part , Model  FROM ctautoparts.nissanpart , ctautoparts.nissan   ;";

MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery, sqlConn);
MySqlDataReader myReader;

try
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
    // int model = myReader.GetOrdinal("model");
    //int model1 = myReader.GetOrdinal("part");
    while (myReader.Read())
    {

    //  string namethestore = myReader.IsDBNull(model)
    //   ? string.Empty
    //  : myReader.GetString("model");

    //   this.carmodel.Text = namethestore;

    //  string namethestore1 = myReader.IsDBNull(model)
    //  ? string.Empty
    // : myReader.GetString("parts");

    ///  this.carpart.Text = namethestore1;
    carmodel.Items.Add(myReader["Model"].ToString());

    carpart.Items.Add(myReader["Part"].ToString());

    }
}
catch (Exception msg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
}
```

Comment: When you run the query from a native mysql prompt, do you get duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks your query is returning duplicated lines. I'd suggest executing them separatedely:

```
try
{
    // POPULATE MODELS
    string modelsQuery = "SELECT Model FROM ctautoparts.nissan;";
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(modelsQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
            // int model = myReader.GetOrdinal("model");
            //int model1 = myReader.GetOrdinal("part");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                carmodel.Items.Add(myReader["Model"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }


    // POPULATE PARTS
    string partsQuery = "SELECT Part FROM ctautoparts.nissanpart;";
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(partsQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
            // int model = myReader.GetOrdinal("model");
            //int model1 = myReader.GetOrdinal("part");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                carpart.Items.Add(myReader["Part"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception msg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
}
```

Comment: string SelectQuery = "SELECT Part , Model FROM ctautoparts.nissanpart , ctautoparts.nissan ;"; <-- thats my query

Comment: @SigbinPInos I edited my answer, I hadn't see your query. It's better and simple to execute two queries instead of only one, since you're not even doing an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: what does this mean? Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SqlDataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CTAUTOPARTS c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CTAUTOPARTS\CTAUTOPARTS\Addinvetory.cs 145

Comment: @SigbinPInos I forgot you're using `MySQL`. I edited my answer, just change all `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` to `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` (respectively).

Comment: BRO! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Add distinct to your select query, so that the duplicates will be removed

Comment: its still duplicate

Comment: How are you sure the problem is the query? What if OP is calling that function multiple times?

Comment: what you mean OP? sorry im new

Comment: @SigbinPInos "Original Poster", [take a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean).

Comment: how can i stop calling them multiple times?